# Man tries to kill a group of people with complex traps

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I don't know the name of this horror movie around 2000-2010. English movie.

1. It's a group of people in a place
2. There is a man in a wheelchair, a blonde woman (called Sarah), a black man (called Cole), a white guy which is supposedly good but is the bad guy, and some more people
3. Bad guy tries to kill everyone for whatever reason (can't remember) through traps
4. Wheelchair guy gets stuck in a refrigerator room (sort of), gets out, goes up in an elevator, shoots a gun and the bullet fires in his direction (dead)
5. A guy turns on a radio and dominoes start falling. He ends up dying 'cause acid gas burns his legs without him noticing
6. Girl goes out to get a cigarette, smokes it and it burns her on the inside
7. Sarah is afraid of water, but in the end she and the bad guy fight underwater for a long time and she ends up killing him because he needed to breathe and she shot him with her hand out of water.
8. P.S. the first scene I remember is a dorm flooded with water and the wheelchair guy is stuck. Lamps fall on the water so that it gets electrified. Cole saves him.

I remember many details but not the movie's name...
I apologize if the format looks terrible but I'm still not used to how this site works.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour), rest assured that the format looks excellent, considering that you're a completely new user (well, even for a not-new user it would be a reasonably well-written question).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is [Mindhunters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0297284/combined) from 2004 with Jonny Lee Miller and Christian Slater:

> On a remote island, the FBI has a training program for their psychological profiling division, called "Mindhunters", used to track down serial killers. The training goes horribly wrong, however, when a group of seven young agents discover that one of them is a serial killer, and is setting about slaying the others. Can the few that are left figure out who the killer is in time?

Every detail you've mentioned is in there (though the black guy is called Gabe). Here's the trailer: